If $I$ is a two-sided ideal of $R$ and $M$ is a left module over $R$, why is $IM$ also a left module over $R$? There is also a related question.
Let $R$ be a ring with unity. If $I$ is a two-sided ideal of $R$ and $M$ is a left module over $R$, then $IM$ is also a left module over $R$, where $IM = \lbrace
{\sum_{i=1}^n a_im_i|a_i\in I, m_i\in M} \rbrace$, and the module structure of $IM$ over $R$ is defined as follows:
$$r \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n a_i m_i := \sum_{i=1}^n r \cdot a_i m_i\ ,r\in R\ .$$
Why is the definition of the module structure of $IM$ over $R$ well-defined? i.e., if
$$x = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i m_i = \sum_{j=1}^l b_j x_j \in IM,$$
then why can we conclude that
$$r \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n a_i m_i = r \cdot \sum_{j=1}^l b_j x_j?$$
The other question is:
If $I$ is just a left ideal of $R$, is there a counterexample such that $IM$ is not a left module over $R$, that is, the above definition of the module structure of $IM$ over $R$ is not well-defined?

General case: If $I$ is a left ideal of the ring $R$, $M$ an $R$-module and $S$ a nonempty subset of $M$. Then $IS=\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}r_ia_i|r_i\in I,a_i\in S, n \in \mathbb{N/\{0\}}\}$ is a submodule of $M$ and thus an $R-$module.

Thank you. Why is the definition of the module structure of $IS$ over $R$ well-defined? How to show that? Or where can I find a reference?

@LiangChen  I think just need to show that $IS$ is a submodule.

Good idea! I get your point.
